# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{2+\cos t}dt$.

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{2+\cos t}dt$$

I thought that using the fundamental theorem of calculus and l'Hospital would provide me with ${\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{2+\cos x}}$, but I don't know if this has a result when ${x\to \infty}$.

Answer (score 4):

The function
$$ f(t)=\frac{1}{2+\cos t}  $$
is periodic with period $2\pi$. Thus, we have that
$$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = N \int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\,dt + \int_0^{x- 2\pi N}f(t)\,dt   $$
with
$$ N = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2\pi} \right\rfloor\,.$$
The second term is bounded by a constant,
$$\left|\int_0^{x- 2\pi N}f(t)\,dt \right| \leq \int_0^{2\pi}|f(t)|\,dt\,.$$

Thus, we have that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2\pi}{x} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2\pi} \right\rfloor \right)\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\,dt =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\,dt\,.$$

The last integral can be easily evaluated and we obtain 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

As $-1\le \cos(t)\le 1$ for any $t$,

$$\frac{1}{2+\cos(t)}\ge \frac{1}{3}$$

So

$$
\int_0^x \frac{1}{2+\cos(t)}  dt \ge \frac{x}{3}
$$

Comment: This may be useful, but does not provide me with an answer for the given limit.

Comment: @user651754 Wouldn't the integral in question tend to $\infty$?

Comment: I did a mistake by not adding everything given. Otherwise, the l'Hospital idea would have had no sense.

Comment: This only shows that the given limit is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{3}$.