# Find the limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\frac{dt}{2+\cos(t)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

**Question:**
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\frac{dt}{2+\cos(t)}$$

**My approach:**

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2+\cos(t)}$  is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$  $\implies$ $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$  is a antiderivative of $f$ $\iff$
$\iff$  $(\int_0^x f(t)\,dt)'=f(x)$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x\frac{dt}{2+\cos(t)}}{x}\stackrel{L'H}{=}\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\int_0^x\frac{dt}{2+\cos (t)}\right)'}{x'}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2+\cos(x)}$$ which does not exist

Note: In order to use L'Hospital rule it is only necessary that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \pm\infty$ , $g$ being the function in the denominator. [This results from the proof which you can see here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof)

The book from which I took this problem says the **answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$**. How do I get to that result, is my approach correct?

Comment: L'hopital's rule says something different: **if** the limit as $x \to \infty$ of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ **exists** and it equal to $L$, **only then** the limit as $x \to \infty$ of $f(x)/g(x)$ exists and is equal to $L$. In your example, you can't say that those two limits are equal, since the one with the derivatives does not exist, as you noticed.

Comment: By the way, the question was already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148444/find-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac1x-int-0x-frac12-cos-tdt?rq=1 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153522/evaluate-limit-of-an-integral-lim-x-to-infty-frac1x-int-0x-fracd?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{2+\cos t}dt$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148444/find-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac1x-int-0x-frac12-cos-tdt)